# How to calculate the integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help, I do not know how to calculate it.

$$C=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{m \cos (\text{x}) \cos (\text{y})+\cos (\text{x})+\cos (\text{y})}{\left((\cos (\text{x})+\cos
 (\text{y})+m)^2+\sin ^2(\text{x})+\sin ^2(\text{y})\right)^{3/2}}dxdy$$

Answer:
This integration is related to condensed matter physics about Chern number. Moreover, it is the Chern number of the **QWZ model**. I have a physical explanation, the answer is 0 or $\pm1$(maybe$\pm2$, to some extent it is an integer I am sure.) when m is in different range. But I really want to know how to calculate it directly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As stated, your question doesn't make sense. You write $\text{kx},\,\text{ky}$ in the integrand, but $dkxdky$ in the infinitesimal element. Does this mean $k^2dxdy$, or should $f(\text{kx},\,\text{ky})dkxdky$ be $f(k_x,\,k_y)dk_xdk_y$? Also, a double integral needs two $\int_a^b$s, which may or may not both satisfy $a=-\pi,\,b=\pi$.

Comment: This time I hope you can get my means. kx ky is a physical mark, it is my fault.

Comment: It still only has one set of bounds.

Comment: It is clear now.

Comment: Perhaps you missed some normalizing constant? Numerical experiment suggests that the integral demonstrates a very interesting behavior as a function of $m$: $I(m)$ is an odd function in $m$, and there exists a constant $c \approx 12.56637$ such that $$ I(m) = \begin{cases} 0, & m<-2 \text{ or } m = 0 \text{ or } m > 2, \\ c/2, &m = -2, \\ c, & -2 < m < 0 \\ -c, & 0 < m < 2 \\ -c/2, & m = 2 \end{cases} $$ At this point, however, I am not sure how to prove this. It might possibly related to the fac that $m=0,\pm2$ are points where the type of the integrand's singularity changes.

Comment: You are right. 12.56637=4\pi, which I have omitted it. But I do not know how to claculate it directly.

Comment: It's a shame I did not recognize that obvious value! I only tried dividing $c$ by $4\pi^2$ as per the usual normalization and gave up... :s

Comment: You are modest. I still want to thank you.